# How do I include dependencies for dr.js?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

I am trying to install dr.js as my javascript documentation. 
Here is a link: https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/dr.js/0.1.1

I uses node.js and npm so I installed. 
I can see there are dependencies. What are they? What do I do with dependencies? Does anyone know how to install dr.js?

How do I include dependencies?

I did

```
npm install dr.js@0.1.1
```

and I got

```
dr.js@0.1.1 ../node_modules/dr.js
├── eve@0.5.0
├── dot@1.0.3
├── markdown@0.5.0 (nopt@2.1.2)
└── topcoat@0.7.5 (topcoat-utils@0.1.3, topcoat-range-base@0.0.3, topcoat-list@0.5.0, topcoat-textarea@0.3.0, topcoat-switch-base@0.1.0, topcoat-search-input-base@0.1.2, topcoat-tab-bar@0.1.0, topcoat-radio-button-base@0.1.1, topcoat-input-base@0.4.1, topcoat-checkbox-base@0.1.3, topcoat-checkbox@0.4.0, topcoat-notification@0.1.1, topcoat-icon-button@0.3.4, topcoat-button-bar-base@0.1.5, topcoat-notification-base@0.0.1, topcoat-textarea-base@0.3.2, topcoat-button-base@0.6.1, topcoat-list-base@0.4.1, topcoat-button-bar@0.1.1, topcoat-radio-button@0.1.2, topcoat-text-input@0.3.4, topcoat-theme@0.5.24, topcoat-search-input@0.3.3, topcoat-button@0.5.5, topcoat-switch@0.1.4, topcoat-range@0.1.0, topcoat-navigation-bar-base@0.4.0, topcoat-navigation-bar@0.4.2)
```

What does this output mean? Does this mean installation is done?
I am very new to node.js and npm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you installed dr.js in your node_modules directory with its dependencies. If you open your dr.js directory you will see there node_modules folder in which are installed it's dependencies, for instance dot, markdown.

The following will install the latest version:

```
npm install dr.js
```

This will install version 0.1.1:

```
npm install dr.js@0.1.1
```